# How to transform csv data into a 3D matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, 3d

The csv file contains 4 columns. First three columns describe X, Y, Z, coordinates and the forth one Q describes a quantitative property in such 3D space.
This array illustrates an example of the input data:

```
DATA = [-3, -1,  1, -9;...
        -3, -1,  2, -6;...
        -3, -1,  3, -3;...
        -3,  0,  1, -6;...
        -3,  0,  2, -3;...
        -3,  0,  3,  0;...
        -3,  1,  1, -3;...
        -3,  1,  2,  0;...
        -3,  1,  3,  3;...
        -2, -1,  1, -6;...
        -2, -1,  2, -3;...
        -2, -1,  3,  0;...
        -2,  0,  1, -3;...
        -2,  0,  2,  0;...
        -2,  0,  3,  3;...
        -2,  1,  1,  0;...
        -2,  1,  2,  3;...
        -2,  1,  3,  6;...
        -1, -1,  1, -3;...
        -1, -1,  2,  0;...
        -1, -1,  3,  3;...
        -1,  0,  1,  0;...
        -1,  0,  2,  3;...
        -1,  0,  3,  6;...
        -1,  1,  1,  3;...
        -1,  1,  2,  6;...
        -1,  1,  3,  9;...
         0, -1,  1,  0;...
         0, -1,  2,  3;...
         0, -1,  3,  6;...
         0,  0,  1,  3;...
         0,  0,  2,  6;...
         0,  0,  3,  9;...
         0,  1,  1,  6;...
         0,  1,  2,  9;...
         0,  1,  3, 12]
```

I would like to plot this data using **scatter3** function:

```
Xo = unique(DATA(:,1));
Yo = unique(DATA(:,2));
Zo = unique(DATA(:,3));
[Xs, Ys, Zs] = meshgrid(Xo, Yo, Zo);

Qs = ???

scatter3(Xs(:),Ys(:),Zs(:),[],Qs(:),'Marker','.')
```

I'm looking for an elegant solution (preferably built-in Matlab function) to accurately extract Qs from the csv input data. (*Currently I'm implementing a complex nested for loop solution, but there must be an easier way to do that...*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)?  `csvread` is specifically designed to read CSV files and place your numerical data into a matrix.  Once you use `csvread`, this should create a `N x 4` matrix of your data in the workspace, so simply extract whichever column(s) you want!  I'm assuming that your CSV file only contains 4 columns of numerical data.

In your case, you want to call `scatter3` this way, assuming that your data is read in to matrix `A` and you have a text file called `text.csv`:

```
A = csvread('text.csv');
scatter3(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3), [], A(:,4), 'Marker', '.');
```

The first, second, third and fourth rows of your CSV data denote the X, Y, Z and Q data respectively, so I'm assuming that you'll just want to plot these 3D co-ordinates using the columns of the matrix.

## Edit

You wish to create a 3D matrix `Qs` that will store the `Q` values for each corresponding `XYZ` tuple.  The trick to do this is to ensure that your XYZ co-ordinates start at index 1.  Once you do this, you can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to determine linear indices or column major indices to populate those values in `Qs`.  To get each dimension to start at 1, you need to find the minimum value of each column of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, subtract by the minimum value then add 1.  The code that you have above to compute the mesh with `meshgrid` is fine.  You just need to determine where in `Q` you need to place values in `Qs`.

As such:

```
%// From your code
Xo = unique(DATA(:,1));
Yo = unique(DATA(:,2));
Zo = unique(DATA(:,3));
[Xs, Ys, Zs] = meshgrid(Xo, Yo, Zo);

%// Now figure out where to access 
%// Qs and copy Q values over
X = DATA(:,1);
Y = DATA(:,2);
Z = DATA(:,3);
Xoffset = X - min(Xo) + 1;
Yoffset = Y - min(Yo) + 1;
Zoffset = Z - min(Zo) + 1;

ind = sub2ind(size(Xs), Yoffset, Xoffset, Zoffset);
Qs = zeros(size(Xs));
Qs(ind) = DATA(:,4);
```

---

`Qs` is now shaped in that 3D matrix that you wanted.  Now, all you have to do is what you did before for `scatter3`:

```
scatter3(Xs(:),Ys(:),Zs(:),[],Qs(:),'Marker','.');
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: So what you are saying, I do not need to apply `meshgrid` in order to use `scatter3`. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @BorisL. - Nope!  Remember, a scatterplot plots a **scattered** bunch of points onto a graph.  You don't need to generate a grid of co-ordinates.  `meshgrid` is unnecessary.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes it works. Yet, I might still need `meshgrid`, as I would like to perform slicing through the volume. `slice(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),A(:,4),[],[],[1 3])` was not possible... Any advice?

Comment: @BorisL. - Your 3D co-ordinates, is there any missing data?  In your 3D grid, will you have any values that are missing, or having a 3D point with no `Q` value?  I can easily extend this post if there is no missing data.

Comment: @BorisL. - OK.  I'll modify my post soon.

Comment: @BorisL. - I've edited my post to place `Q` into a 3D matrix.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Now both plots `scatter3` and `slice` can be generated from the same matrix. By the way, I would probably never discover `sub2ind` on my own, as all my Google queries did not bring me even close to it...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I'm hitting another roadblock. Actually, the proposed calculation of `Xoffset, Yoffset, Zoffset` is working as long as the input `X,Y,Z` are integers, but I also have data where that is not the case. Could you propose a more generic solution to calculate `Xoffset, Yoffset, Zoffset`. I'm still tempted to implement for loops, but I hope there is a more elegant solution...

Comment: @BorisL. Is the resolution in each dimension the same?... like would the difference between the `x` values be the same for all of the points?  If it is, then there's still another way to do this to convert those values into integer.  If the points have a non-uniform distance between near points then I don't see any other way other than a `for` loop.  You may increase performance by perhaps using `find` in your loop but I can't see any other solution for a non-uniform grid.

Comment: No, X and Y have uniform resolution, but different step size. Z is arbitrary, no step size. For example: `Z = [100; 1000; 2500; 6000; 11000]`. Currently I calculate the indices as follows: `Zoffset = zeros(size(data(:,3))); for N = 1:length(Zo), Zoffset(data(:,3)==Zo(N))=N; end`

Comment: @BorisL. Without knowing the step size in each dimension, it would be hard to do it without any loops.  I think what you have is the only way I can think of for now!